# How to code foreach loop in mail message

Tags: php

I am confused by the use of single and double quotation marks, echo, and $message .=

I cannot figure out how to code a foreach loop inside my $message to output the cart items. The thead part works, but the tbody area is flawed. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Initialize variables
$name = $telephone = $email = $jim_gmail  = '';

// Post data from @quote-form.html.php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['action'] ) ) {

// Sanitize and post data to variables
$company = sanitize( $_POST['company'] );
$name = sanitize( $_POST['name'] );
$telephone = sanitize( $_POST['telephone'] );
$email = sanitize( $_POST['email'] );

// Assign $name value to SESSION variable for use @thankyou.html.php
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;

// Initialize and declare variables for script validation
$errMsg = '';
$telephone_pattern = '/^((([0-9]{1})*[- .(]*([0-9]{3})[- .)]*[0-9]{3}[- .]*[0-9]{4})+)*$/';
$alpha_only_pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z]*$/';
$email_pattern = '/^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$/';
$integers_pattern = '/^[0-9]*$/';

// Validate user data before submitting to server
if(empty($name) || empty($telephone)  || empty($email))
{
    $errMsg = "*Name, telephone and email address required.<br>";
    include 'error.html.php';

}
elseif (preg_match($email_pattern,$email) === 0 ) 
{
    $errMsg = "*Please enter a valid email address.<br>";
    include 'error.html.php';

}
else
{ 

/* Prepare message for e-mail */
/* set e-mail recipient */

$jim_gmail  = 'jim@gmail.com';


// Three required arguments ($to, $subject, $message)
$to  = "$jim_gmail"; 
$subject = "Buyer for CraneHeli";
$from = "$email";
$message = // contents of report in $message
"
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h3>Parts Buyer</h3>
    <p>Company: $company</p>
    <p>Name:  $name</p>
    <p>Telephone: $telephone</p>
    <p>Email: $email</p>
    <h3>Please quote the following:</h3>    
    <table name='contact_seller' style='border-collapse:collapse';> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>    
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($cart as $item): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>$item['id']</td>
                <td>$item['part_number']</td>
                <td>$item['description']</td>
                <td>$item['quantity']</td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>End of buyer data report</p> 
    <hr />     
</body>
</html>
"; //end of $message

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";      // code to send HTML on UNIX
$headers .= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $jim_gmail . "\r\n";     // works
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $jim_gmail . "\r\n";     // works

    // Send message using mail() function 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

    // Check to see if headers not sent. If true, redirect to thank_you.php page
    if(!headers_sent()){
        header('Location: thankyou.html.php');
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "<span class='errMsg'>Message sent successfully!</span><br><br>" .
            "Cannot redirect, please click this <a " .
            "href=\".\">link</a> instead\n";
    } 
    exit();        
}

/******* Functions used *******/
    function sanitize($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong, 1. close `</thead><tbody>";`, 2. `$temp = ''; foreach($cart as $item){ $temp .= "<tr><td>{$item['id']}</td><td>{$item['part_number']}</td><td>{$item['description']}</td><td>{$item['quantity']}</td></tr>"; } `, 3. after that, `$message .= $temp . "</tbody></table><p>End of buyer data report</p><hr /></body></html>
";"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're nearly there:

```
$message = // contents of report in $message
        "
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <h3>Parts Buyer</h3>
            <p>Company: $company</p>
            <p>Name:  $name</p>
            <p>Telephone: $telephone</p>
            <p>Email: $email</p>
            <h3>Please quote the following:</h3>    
            <table name='contact_seller' style='border-collapse:collapse';> 
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Part Number</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>    
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
                    foreach($cart as $item) { 
                        $message .="<tr>
                            <td>" . $item['id'] ."</td>
                            <td>".$item['part_number']."</td>
                            <td>".$item['description']."</td>
                            <td>".$item['quantity']."</td>
                        </tr>";
                     } 
                $message .= "</tbody>
            </table>
            <p>End of buyer data report</p> 
            <hr />     
        </body>
        </html>"; //end of $message
```

Take note specifically of:

```
<tbody>";
                    foreach($cart as $item) {
                        $message .="<tr>
                            <td>" . $item['id'] ."</td>
                            <td>".$item['part_number']."</td>
                            <td>".$item['description']."</td>
                            <td>".$item['quantity']."</td>
                        </tr>";
                     }
                $message .= "</tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amo for two things: (1) your speedy expert reply; and (2) for your encouragement in saying "You're nearly there." I will now study your solution to understand how it. Thank you for taking your time to assist me.