# Format email correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way to **structure the email message in blocks** in such way that with *$message.=*  I can "stack" the necessary info where needed, but cannot figure out the correct format. For instance:

1. Can/Should the first *$message =* have the  etc tags?
2. Can/should I add the  etc tags to each *$message .=* statement?
3. How to keep it all visibly (in the code) organised so it later will be understandable?

My setup would be to create 3 if/else sections that add either the info that nothing is found or if found the array in a table. **So far I have:**

```
$message = echo "<strong>SYNC INFORMATION</strong><br>";

//Section/table 1
if(!trips_missing){
    $message .= echo "<strong>Missing trips: 0</strong>";   
}else{
    $message .= "<html>
                    <head>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table name='Following trips are missing'>
                            <tread>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>End</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Boat</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Itinerary</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Places</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>USD<br></strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tread>
                            <tbody>";
                                foreach($trips_missing as $array)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>".$array['Date']."</td>
                                        <td>".$array['End']."</td>
                                        <td>".$array['Boat'].""&nbsp;"</td>
                                        <td>".$array['Itinerary']."</td>
                                        <td align="right">".$array['Places']."</td>
                                        <td align="right">".round($array['USD']."</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            $message.="</tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br>
                    </body>
                </html>";

// Followed by 2 more if/else for section 2 and 3
```

Feel free to crush my euphoria that I could produce the above, if it doesn't kill you it makes you stronger. All help is appreciated, no matter how formulated.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with MySQL?  If not, then you might want to remove that tag.

Comment: Well, your `foreach` loop is full of syntax errors.  Aside from that, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Appologies, hanging from previous question. Will remove.

Comment: Please: Always debug and test your code, as far as possible, before you put it in a question.

Comment: Actually, was most of the code comes from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442741/how-to-code-foreach-loop-in-mail-message

Comment: Remove those spurious `echo` statements. e.g. `$message = echo "<strong>SYNC INFORMATION</strong><br>";` should be `$message =  "<strong>SYNC INFORMATION</strong><br>";`

Comment: Clear. The foreach loop was based on a wrong answer, the echo was overlooked as table was created for testing first to show in browser. But anyone some answer on the questions? Where to enter <html> and where not

Comment: Also, shouldn't `<tread>` be `<thead>`?  Another typo I guess.  But it's not clear what you're asking.  What's wrong with specifically the `<html>` tag?  It might not be needed as the body of an email, but is it doing any harm?  What's the *actual problem* here?

Comment: The only thing I try to figure out if how to set this up in such a way that I can create a $message and add stuff to it where needed. As such I don't understand how to set this up correctly. Use <html> etc on each .= , only on the first, not at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your foreach loop as:

```
foreach($trips_missing as $array){
                                 $message .= "  <tr>
                                        <td>".$array['Date']."</td>
                                        <td>".$array['End']."</td>
                                        <td>".$array['Boat']."&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>".$array['Itinerary']."</td>
                                        <td align='right'>".$array['Places']."</td>
                                        <td align='right'>".round($array['USD'],2)."</td>
                                    </tr>";
                                }
```

Comment: Thanks DarkBee, this helps! But how to handle the <htlml> tags etc. Park them in the first $message and then add consistently with .= ?

Comment: @John i'm not the one who answerd this. I just editted a syntax error But yes that's what u need to do

Comment: @DarkBee, read all the answers, now that I was clumsy with typos etc and as such did not move forward to get structural answer on the 3 questions. Will just try to create $message with all the <html> tags and add stuff to it without. Posted as writing on localhost MAMP and testing email stuff troublesome.

Comment: @John the "best" way to solve this is separating views and logic all together. A good way to do this is start using a template engine like `twig`. Just my 2 cents though

Comment: Found more answers on stackoverflow similar to yours, but upon following them non worked. Somehow seems not acceptable to put $message within a foreach loop. Also should the last curly bracket have a semicolumn?

Answer (score 0):

After another hour searching Stack, the answer of DarkBee and thinking logically, I believe this is the complete answer. It seems to works well.

```
$message = '<html><body>';
if(!$trips_missing){
    $message .= "<p><strong>Missing trips: 0</strong></p></body></html>";   
    }
else{
    $message .= "<p><strong>Following trips are missing</strong></p>
                <table>
                    <thread>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Start</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>End</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Boat</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Itinerary</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Places</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>USD<br></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thread>
                    <tbody>";
    foreach($trips_missing as $array){
        $message .= "
            <tr>
                <td>".$array['Date']."</td>
                <td>".$array['End']."</td>
                <td>".$array['Boat']."</td>
                <td>".$array['Itinerary']."</td>
                <td align='right'>".$array['Places']."&nbsp;</td>
                <td align='right'>".round($array['USD'],2)."</td>
            </tr>";
    };
    $message .="</tbody></table></body></html>";

};
```

So it seems the eventual structure of  . ..  should be in order inside $message. Maybe it helps another simple soul like me...

Comment: One mystery left. Upon Vardump shows a double quote at the end. No big deal, but too blind to find this . . .